# Jetty HTTP server ip and port binding error: ServiceConstructionException

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, cxf

[eclipse-jetty] Could not start Jetty server on port 9,091: Cannot assign requested address

I am using jetty HTTP server to publish REST Web Services.

Configurations:
server-ip : 20.121.21.22
port: 8081

For above configuration, it throws below exception.

> org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
>
> Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not start Jetty
>   server on port 8,081: Cannot assign requested address     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:386)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:95)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:131)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:192)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested
>   address   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:124)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:209)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:375)
>     ... 8 more

In Error Message port showing is 8,081 but i have configured is 8081.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens only when IP specified is not own interface. 
Socket is not able to bind to that IP, 
Actually error is correct but **error message is wrong** because it shows wrong port in message.